# Change background color of UILabel in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uibackgroundcolor

I have an array of `UILabels`.

```
UILabel *tag = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offx,offy, 200, 50)];
[tag setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[tag setFont:tagText.font];
tag.numberOfLines = 0;
[tag setText:tagText.text];
[self addSubview:tag];
[_tagArray addObject:tag];
```

Then later on I would like to change the background color of one of the labels in this array.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_tagArray lastObject]);
UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[_tagArray lastObject];
[l setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[_tagArray lastObject] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In the log, I'm getting the label I created but the background color is not changing.

> UILabel: 0x15fec10c0; frame = (6 78; 52 29); text = 'hi'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x174298240

Comment: How do you know the background color isn't changing? The code you posted looks fine.

Comment: @rmaddy I `[self addSubview:tag];` add it to my view.

Comment: You might need to post somemore code because your code looks completely fine and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   NSArray *_tagArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"First",@"Second",@"Third",nil];
             for (int xOff=0; xOff<[_tagArray count]; xOff++) 
            {
                UILabel *tag = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOff,xOff*50, 200, 50)];
                [tag setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
                tag.numberOfLines = 0;
                [tag setText:[_tagArray objectAtIndex:xOff]];
                [tag setTag:xOff];

                [self.view addSubview:tag];
            }

            UILabel *l = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
            [l setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

            UILabel *l2 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
            [l2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Please explain what was wrong with the code in the question and explain how this answer solves the issue. Code-only answers are not appropriate to SO.

Comment: @rmaddy The code posted is not enough to understand what went wrong, may be a main queue issue or the or conflicting tags, so just posted the working code, shall I remove the answer ?

Answer (score -1):

```
    _tagArray = [_tagArray replaceObjectAtIndex:_tagArray.count-1 withObject:l];
```

Use this because you taken last object and changed the color of that object.After that just replace that last object from the array.And remove last line of code.

Comment: This is not necessary and it has no affect. And this code won't even compile.